# javascript to add rows to a table dynamically

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out how to use javascript to add rows to a table dynamically. I tested without the table and can get the data but am stumped on populating the table.

I have a function call on a button that is supposed to populate the table. below is my code so far:

```
  <table id="tblData" class="pure-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Staff</th>
                        <th>Orders</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <!--<tr class="pure-table-odd">
                            <td>Jim</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                        </tr>-->

                </tbody>
            </table>


 function getData()
 {
var soData = JSON.parse(staffOrders);
var i = 0;
var c = getRowCount(); 

//build table
var table = document.getElementById("tblData");

while (i <= c) {
    //alert(soData[i].staffName + " had " + soData[i].orders + " orders.");
    //"<td>" + soData[i].staffName + "</td>"
    //"<td>" + soData[i].orders + "</td>"
    i++;
}
 }
```

Comment: insertRow/insertCell or appendChild

Comment: @user3479671 the OP clearly already knows how to get the data - that's what AJAX is for.  Subsequently adding it to the DOM is nothing to do with AJAX.

Comment: You should consider using `createDocumentFragment` to build up the row structure and then append the fragment to the table. Much more efficient.

Comment: @Alnitak - My mistake, I misread the question and took it for a duplicate.  I'll remove the comment now

Comment: not sure I'm following the createdocumentfragment concept

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the DOM API for the HTML table element. It's documented at
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_table.asp

Here's an example taken from http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp :

```
// Find a <table> element with id="myTable":
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

// Create an empty <tr> element and add it to the 1st position of the     table:
var row = table.insertRow(0);

// Insert new cells (<td> elements) at the 1st and 2nd position of the     "new" <tr> element:
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

// Add some text to the new cells:
cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
```

Comment: Please do not cite w3schools, use MDN for examples (e.g. [*Creating a HTML table dynamically*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Traversing_an_HTML_table_with_JavaScript_and_DOM_Interfaces#Overview_of_Sample1.html)) and an appropriate W3C specification or standard for, well, standards.

Comment: In addition to what RobG said, here's a better reference: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Traversing_an_HTML_table_with_JavaScript_and_DOM_Interfaces](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Traversing_an_HTML_table_with_JavaScript_and_DOM_Interfaces)

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```js
window.onload = function(){
function getData() {
      var soData = [{orders : 'order1', staffName : 'staffName1'}, {orders : 'order2', staffName : 'staffName2'}]
      var i = 0;
      var c = 2;
    
      //build table
      var table_body = document.getElementById("tblData").getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
      while (i <= c) {
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tr.className = "pure-table-odd"; // add class in tr
        var td1 = document.createElement('td');
        td1.innerHTML = soData[i].orders;
        var td2 = document.createElement('td');
        td2.innerHTML = soData[i].staffName;
        tr.appendChild(td1);
        tr.appendChild(td2);
        table_body.appendChild(tr);
        i++;
      }
};
  getData();
}
```

```html
<table id="tblData" class="pure-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Staff</th>
                        <th>Orders</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <!--<tr class="pure-table-odd">
                            <td>Jim</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                        </tr>-->

                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: no luck implementing this as it didn't render the code

Comment: how would i add class="pure-table-odd" to a tr?

Comment: ok you can add `className` in tr `DOM` `tr.className = "pure-table-odd"` see updated code

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getData() {
  var responseData = [{
    "staffName": "Wilkerson Bowman",
    "orders": 26
  }, {
    "staffName": "Finley Nunez",
    "orders": 26
  }, {
    "staffName": "Katie Estrada",
    "orders": 7
  }];
  var thead = document.querySelector('#tblData thead');

  responseData.forEach(function(data) {
    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    row.innerHTML = '<td>' + data.staffName + '</td><td>' + data.orders + '</td>';
    thead.appendChild(row);
  });
}

getData();
```

```html
<table id="tblData" class="pure-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Staff</th>
      <th>Orders</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: According to caniuse.com this works in all browsers except <= IE8